# Net monitor - RBP3+ setup

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, monitoring

Good day everyone.
I am looking to get some use out of my RBP3 model b as I have only used retro pie on it before and I feel it is a waste, I have since then setup a Desktop pc for emulation etc., I want to really dig into networking and monitoring my local LAN network traffic as I have 2 ISP setup for work and play. I want to start with my first ISP monitor traffic and go from there and then so forth. I am not new to pie so I have some XP.

I currently have RBP3= with 32gb San disk class 10 microSD-card, Cana kit with heat sinks all working no issue like I said I really have not pushed the pi nor used it online for numerous hours. I’m thinking of either traffic monitor for tcp stack, ip protocols, ports, destination and host IP monitoring, block ads without using a chrome extension (want to get away from google chrome) Stop paying for AV from Bitdefender as well, other options as well for net monitoring.

My current router for 1st isp is netgear XR500 with Dumas which cannot be flashed with DDWRT or open wrt. I currently have an 8-port net gear switch that is managed and can-do port mirroring however with as many devices I have I think I will need to get a 16port managed switch to do net traffic monitoring for port mirroring, lend me some advice.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Please write in paragraphs and try to use proper punctuation.